# How to catch tab change events on a GWT TabLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt

I am developing a GWT application which uses the standart GWT TabLayoutPanel. 
Just realized that this component doesn't have an event to notify you when a tabs gets changed.

It has a getSelectedIndex() method, but I need an event so that other parts of the UI can react to changes.

My initial idea was to put a component that will always be bound and will fire an event when it gets loaded. It seams like a hack and I haven't figured out how yet.

Does anyone know what a good way to catch the tab change event would be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never worked with this widget, but isn't [`addSelectionHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html#addSelectionHandler%28com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.SelectionHandler%29) what you need?

Comment: Thank you ! not sure how I missed that.